# Render data on two templates from one function Django

Tags: django, function, templates, render

Hi i need to **render** the data on two templates from one function my code is

```
def stylepoints(request):
        a=Product.objects.all()[:3] 
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:        
                cursor.execute("SELECT facebook_id,name FROM django_facebook_facebookuser WHERE user_id  = %s ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1",[request.user.id])
        except Exception as e:        
                return HttpResponse("error in fetching Friends")
        rows_affected=cursor.rowcount
        if rows_affected > 0:
                row1 = cursor.fetchall()
                row12 = row1[0]
        else:
                row12 = ''
        value = request.user.id
        cursor12 = connection.cursor()
        cursor12.execute("SELECT Distinct email FROM myaccount_invitation WHERE reference_id = %s AND status  = 1 AND invitation_type = 2",[value])
        friend = cursor12.fetchall()
        if friend:
                friends = friend[0]
        return render_to_response('swf.html',{'a':a,'userf':row12,'friendshow':friend} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

like in this i have send a data to one template name as

> swf.html

but i need to send the data also to another template such as

> swf2.html

please tell me can i render a data to two templates

Comment: Can't you write one template and include these two in it?

Comment: no i need to show them on different url

Comment: Both urls handled by `stylepoints` views? How would you choose which template to use?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "sending data" to two templates? How will those templates be used? Why would whatever's calling this view care which or how many templates were used?

Answer (score 1):

```
def view1(request):
    template_name='swf1.html'
    return stylepoints(request, template_name)

def view2(request):
    template_name='swf2.html'
    return stylepoints(request, template_name)


def stylepoints(request, template_name):
        a=Product.objects.all()[:3] 
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:        
                cursor.execute("SELECT facebook_id,name FROM django_facebook_facebookuser WHERE user_id  = %s ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1",[request.user.id])
        except Exception as e:        
                return HttpResponse("error in fetching Friends")
        rows_affected=cursor.rowcount
        if rows_affected > 0:
                row1 = cursor.fetchall()
                row12 = row1[0]
        else:
                row12 = ''
        value = request.user.id
        cursor12 = connection.cursor()
        cursor12.execute("SELECT Distinct email FROM myaccount_invitation WHERE reference_id = %s AND status  = 1 AND invitation_type = 2",[value])
        friend = cursor12.fetchall()
        if friend:
                friends = friend[0]
        return render_to_response(template_name,{'a':a,'userf':row12,'friendshow':friend} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```